# Bootstrap - how to make one of list elements always collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a list using Bootstrap, where all the time the last clicked list item is collapsed. Following the code from https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if Collapsible Group 1 is clicked, then none of the list items is collapsed. I want if an item is clicked, it cannot be uncollapsed. An item should be uncollapsed only if another list item is selected. How can I make that the last clicked item is always collapse, so if it is clicked again it will not uncollapse?

Comment: approve the edit to convert code to a snippet or add a fiddle please.

Comment: easiest way to use the plgin here: https://jqueryui.com/accordion

Comment: The item's behavior is relying on Bootstrap to define. If you need it to do something different, you need to create your own javascript that will collapse it or not.

Comment: @techhunter I am working with Bootstrap, not jQuery, I copy+paste it from the link you provided but not functioning

Comment: You've included the jQuery file, so you **are** using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, but when I put it on my angular 2 application, it's not working, I don't now why

Comment: @user1680859 I have used it in few of my application pages. i is working perfectly alright. Include required libraries. And tell me what error are you getting by inspecting your code.

Comment: @techhunter I am not getting error, but I guess the problem is that I am not including th function properly. Working with Angular 2 (very beginning) and not sure where should I put it. I put it in the index.html file, but somehow it is ignoring it, doesn't give any error, but is not functioning. It seems I should put it in some .ts file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jquery solve for your issue. From the comments on the question, It sounds like that jquery is ok to use? (otherwise, please specify a language)

I am using `event.stopPropagation();` to prevent the event from bubbling to the default bootstrap event listeners.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("[data-toggle='collapse']").click(function(event) {
    var index = $(this).index("[data-toggle='collapse']");
    if ($(".panel-collapse:eq(" + index + ")").is(":visible")) event.stopPropagation()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am a beginner in web development, just started using Angular 2 and Bootstrap, not sure if this is an issue, but used your code in my project (in index.html file) and it's not functioning, can not understand why

Comment: @user1680859 Well if you are using angular2, where are you puitting the code, in a `.js` or `.ts` file? Does it just not work, or does it throw errors?

Comment: the code is in .ts, but I put your code in the index.html file, in the <head> part, inside a script tag, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: You can try and wrap it in a document.ready function (I edited the question)... However, when I get time, I will create a typescript example for you, which will be far better.

Comment: this is nice, thnx @Zze

Answer (score -1):

Please check Angularjs Accordion. Below link might help you

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: It is the same as my example, it you click on it - it will collapse, if you click again - it will uncollapse